# ADO.NET + Winforms inserting into SQL Server CE database

Tags: .net, winforms, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I have the following problem, when I try to read data from table in my SQL Server CE database using `SqlCeDataReader` it works, but when I try to insert new values into table it doesn't work.

This is my approach `conn` is global and `conn.Open()` is caled in the `OnFormLoad` event handler.

```
conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = Database1.sdf; Persist Security Info=False");
conn.Open();

SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText =string.Format("INSERT INTO Emails(Email) VALUES('{0}')", textBox2.Text);

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("error type {0}", ex.GetType().ToString()));
}
```

Of course when I try to execute this insert manually through Database Query it works fine, but in code it doesn't. And no exception is caught...

Comment: **Warning** - your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in ypur bin/debug folder for a copy of the database file with data on it. Solution is to not include the database file in your project, and use a full path in the conection string.